# Gson calls my JSON "map". How can I change the element/root name?

Tags: java, json, dictionary, object, gson

I'm using Java to print a JSON object (containing several objects). I would like to print that object in JSON style.
So I use Gson to make a String out of it, which is then printed. But it always prints "map" as first element/root! Could anyone help with that, please?
It prints it like that:

```
{
   "map" : {
      "swimmers" : {
         "Gold" : "Joan",
         "Silver" : "Mik",
         "Bronze" : "Vy"
       }, {
       "runners" : {
         "Gold" : "Ann",
         "Silver" : "X"
         "Bronze" : "Y"
       }
   }
}
```

Where does the 'map' come from? Is it possible to change?
I would like there not be a 'map' - I actually tried it to be called 'January', which did not work. This solution would be optimal:

```
{
   "January" : {
      "athletes 1" : {
         "Gold" : "Joan",
         "Silver" : "Mik",
         "Bronze" : "Vy"
       }, {
       "athletes 2" : {
         "Gold" : "Ann",
         "Silver" : "X"
         "Bronze" : "Y"
       }
   }
}
```

This is my code:

```
JSONObject myObject = new JSONObject();

for (int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++) {
      
   // ...cut out code here where I received gold, silver and bronze...
       
   Athlete currentAthlete = new Athlete(gold, silver, bronze);
   myObject.put("athletes "+i, currentAthlete);
   }

Gson gson = new Gson();
jsonString = gson.toJson(myObject);
System.out.println(jsonString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `org.json.JSONObject`, with Google's `com.google.gson.JsonObject`, and add a parent like so:

```
JsonObject root = new JsonObject();
JsonObject myObject = new JsonObject();

for (int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++) {
    Athlete currentAthlete = new Athlete(gold, silver, bronze);
    myObject.addProperty("athletes " + i, currentAthlete);
}

Gson gson = new Gson();
root.add("January", myObject);
String jsonString = gson.toJson(root);
System.out.println(jsonString);
```

You could also just use `root.getAsString()` instead of `gson.toJson(root)`